# method overloading from parent class up in the MRO in case of multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python

I have 2 classes cls1 and cls2 and a child class chld that extends both of them

Both cls1 and cls2 have method callMyName()

if I want to call callMyName() from cls 1 which is up in MRO from chld how can I 
do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have basic understanding from this code snippet :

```
class cls1(object):
   def callMyName(self):
      print('cls1.method')
      super(cls1, self).method()  

class cls2(object):
   def callMyName(self):
     print('cls2.method')


class chld(cls1, cls2):
   pass

chld.mro()
[<class '__main__.chld'>, <class '__main__.cls1'>, <class    '__main__.cls2'>, <type 'object'>]
chld().callMyName()
cls1.callMyName
cls2.callMyName
```